# How can I reference individual cells in a range address like "$A$2,$C$2,$E$2"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new at Excel VBA with a noob question about referencing range values.  Fortunately, my question is small.

Here is my Excel VBA Code sample

```
Sub Testing()

Set WS = Excel.ActiveSheet : Set R = WS.Range("$C$2,$E$2,$G$2")

R.Select 'Success, highlights only the cells defined by my range address

Debug.Print R.Cells(, 1), R.Cells(, 2), R.Cells(, 3)

'Returns the values for $C$2, $D$2 and $E$2 - not what I wanted

End Sub
```

Since the `R.Select` method knows to highlight only the 3 cells in my address, is there a code solution for the `R` object to return only the values in my three cells and weed out the other stuff in between?

Your help is greatly appreciated.  I'm just trying to get launched.

Comment: Could you please add expected output for a given input ?

Comment: Use a `for each cell in r.cells` loop instead.

Comment: Rory, that's it!  I tested it and your solution worked with beautiful simplicity.  Thank you so much.  This is my first question I've ever posted on Stack Overflow.  It brings another question.  How do I accept your answer since your response appears in comments?  I see a little flag beside your comment (which is the answer that I needed) but when I highlight it the box says "Flag this comment for serious problems..."  Definitely not what I want to do.  My question is answered... Problem solved...  Much gratitude.

Comment: So nice to see an OP asking how to accept for once!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a range that consists of discontinuous ranges, each separate range is represented by a different area.

So, for your example, to return the cells in the selection, you need something like:

```
With R.Cells
    Debug.Print .Areas(1), .Areas(2), .Areas(3)
End With
```

When, as in your example, you don't specify an `Area`, the default is `Areas(1)`, so you are returning the offset from the first cell in the first Area.

Comment: I know saying thanks in my comment is discouraged but the solutions you and Rory offered not only solved my problem but also opened my eyes to the real power of a range object.  In the handful of times I have coded with a range object I just thought it was a single object - a grouping of cells - and the only way to navigate it was with (row,column) offsets.  I had no idea about Areas - that functionality completely slipped off my radar. This is one small problem solved and one giant leap for my coding future!  I won't forget this one.